# SQL Query Returning Multiple Records when only single records should be returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that I am running with multiple joins to return the required results however, when add into my select statement this field requirements `MX.TFNO AS 'BULK TO SPLIT REFERENCE'` I get duplicate rows of data that are incorrect yet when I comment out this line, the query works correctly yet without the data that should be returned into the above mentioned column.

Below is my query.  Please note that I have a join that I have commented out for table `MPEXOR` as I have yet set up this table in our datalake to pull in that data.

```
SELECT distinct
MP.SUNO AS 'SUPPLIER',
CI.SUNM AS 'SUPPLIER NAME',
MP.FACI AS 'FACILITY',
MP.WHLO AS 'WAREHOUSE',
MP.OURR AS 'SUPPLIER PO',
CONCAT(MM.BUAR ,'/', MP.PROJ) AS 'PO GROUP',
MP.PUNO AS 'PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER',
    IIF (MP.PUNO LIKE '533%', 'SPLIT',
    IIF (MP.PUNO LIKE '511%', 'BULK', '')) as 'PO TYPE',
--MX.TFNO AS 'BULK TO SPLIT REFERENCE',
MP.PNLI AS 'PO LINE NUMBER',
MP.ITNO AS 'ITEM NUMBER',
MP.PITD AS 'STYLE',
MH.TX15 AS 'SIZE',
MH.TY15 AS 'COLOR',
MM.BUAR AS 'BRAND',
CONVERT(varchar,MP.DWDT, 101) AS 'EX FACTORY ORIGINAL DATE',
CONVERT(varchar,MP.CODT,101) AS 'REVISED EX FACTORY DATE',
    IIF (MP.MODL = 'S', 'OCEAN',
    IIF (MP.MODL = 'C', 'COURIER',
    IIF (MP.MODL = 'G', 'CONSIGNEE OPTION',
    IIF (MP.MODL = 'H', 'CUSTOMER PICK UP',
    IIF (MP.MODL = 'M', 'MOTOR',
    IIF (MP.MODL = 'A', 'AIR', '')))))) as 'DELIVERY METHOD',
MP.ORQA AS 'ORDERED QTY',
MF.UCOS AS 'COST PRICE',
MP.PUPR AS 'PURCHASE PRICE',
MP.PUST AS 'PO LOW STATUS',
MP.PUSL AS 'PO HIGH STATUS',
MP.ORCO AS 'COUNTRY OF ORIGIN'
--MX.HREF AS 'PO REFERENCE'
FROM MPLINE MP
INNER JOIN CIDMAS CI WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON CI.CONO = MP.CONO
    AND CI.SUNO = MP.SUNO
    AND CI.DELETED = 'N'
LEFT JOIN MITFAC MF WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON MF.CONO = MP.CONO
    AND MF.FACI = MP.FACI
    AND MF.ITNO = MP.ITNO
    AND MF.DELETED = 'N'
LEFT JOIN MITMAH MH WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON MH.CONO = MP.CONO
    AND MH.ITNO = MP.ITNO
    AND MH.DELETED = 'N'
LEFT JOIN MITMAS MM WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON MM.CONO = MP.CONO
    AND MM.ITNO = MP.ITNO
    AND MM.DELETED = 'N'
LEFT JOIN MPHEAD MX WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON MX.CONO = MP.CONO
    AND MX.SUNO = MP.SUNO
    AND MX.FACI = MP.FACI
    AND MX.WHLO = MP.WHLO
    AND MX.ORTY = MP.ORTY
    AND MX.DELETED = 'N'
--LEFT JOIN MPEXOR ME
    --ON ME.CONO = MP.CONO
    --AND ME.PUNO = MP.PUNO
WHERE MP.PUST < 50
    AND MP.PUSL < 50
    AND MP.PUNO = '5330000172'
--ORDER BY MP.PUNO, MP.PNLI
;
```

Here is the return result with MX.TFNO in place

```
SUPPLIER    SUPPLIER NAME   FACILITY    WAREHOUSE   SUPPLIER PO PO GROUP    PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER   PO TYPE BULK TO SPLIT REFERENCE PO LINE NUMBER  ITEM NUMBER STYLE   SIZE    COLOR   BRAND   EX FACTORY ORIGINAL DATE    REVISED EX FACTORY DATE DELIVERY METHOD ORDERED QTY COST PRICE  PURCHASE PRICE  PO LOW STATUS   PO HIGH STATUS  COUNTRY OF ORIGIN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT       1   P001656-03162XL ALAYA-SF    2XL Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   3.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT       2   P001656-0316L   ALAYA-SF    L   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   20.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT       3   P001656-0316M   ALAYA-SF    M   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   25.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT       4   P001656-0316S   ALAYA-SF    S   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   16.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT       5   P001656-0316XL  ALAYA-SF    XL  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   12.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT       6   P001656-0316XS  ALAYA-SF    XS  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   4.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29371    1   P001656-03162XL ALAYA-SF    2XL Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   3.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29371    2   P001656-0316L   ALAYA-SF    L   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   20.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29371    3   P001656-0316M   ALAYA-SF    M   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   25.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29371    4   P001656-0316S   ALAYA-SF    S   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   16.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29371    5   P001656-0316XL  ALAYA-SF    XL  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   12.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29371    6   P001656-0316XS  ALAYA-SF    XS  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   4.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29373    1   P001656-03162XL ALAYA-SF    2XL Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   3.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29373    2   P001656-0316L   ALAYA-SF    L   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   20.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29373    3   P001656-0316M   ALAYA-SF    M   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   25.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29373    4   P001656-0316S   ALAYA-SF    S   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   16.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29373    5   P001656-0316XL  ALAYA-SF    XL  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   12.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#29373    6   P001656-0316XS  ALAYA-SF    XS  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   4.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#427  1   P001656-03162XL ALAYA-SF    2XL Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   3.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#427  2   P001656-0316L   ALAYA-SF    L   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   20.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#427  3   P001656-0316M   ALAYA-SF    M   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   25.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#427  4   P001656-0316S   ALAYA-SF    S   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   16.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#427  5   P001656-0316XL  ALAYA-SF    XL  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   12.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   PO#427  6   P001656-0316XS  ALAYA-SF    XS  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   4.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
```

Here is the return result without MX.TFNO in place

```
SUPPLIER    SUPPLIER NAME   FACILITY    WAREHOUSE   SUPPLIER PO PO GROUP    PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER   PO TYPE PO LINE NUMBER  ITEM NUMBER STYLE   SIZE    COLOR   BRAND   EX FACTORY ORIGINAL DATE    REVISED EX FACTORY DATE DELIVERY METHOD ORDERED QTY COST PRICE  PURCHASE PRICE  PO LOW STATUS   PO HIGH STATUS  COUNTRY OF ORIGIN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   1   P001656-03162XL ALAYA-SF    2XL Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   3.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   2   P001656-0316L   ALAYA-SF    L   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   20.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   3   P001656-0316M   ALAYA-SF    M   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   25.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   4   P001656-0316S   ALAYA-SF    S   Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   16.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   5   P001656-0316XL  ALAYA-SF    XL  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   12.000000   58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
5046    ZHEJIANG AMP GLOBE IMP & EXP CO LTD US1 U01     SK/FW21 5330000172  SPLIT   6   P001656-0316XS  ALAYA-SF    XS  Juniper SK  20210809    0   OCEAN   4.000000    58.750000   47.500000   20  20  CN
```

Comment: Does the MX.TFNO return different value in each row? or is each row IDENTICAL ?

Comment: Do you *really* "need" all those `NOLOCK` hints? You *do* understand what it does, right? Considering you are using against all the tables, apart from `MPLINE`, why are you not changing the isolation level?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) SImplify!!! [mcve]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it returns different values but should not be.   I have attached what populates in MX.TFNO when it is added.  For this records for the purchase order data i am collecting, for this particular PO 5330000172, the field TFNO is blanks and should only return 6 records and this column data should be blank.

Comment: *"it returns different values but should not be"* Are they, perhaps, ghost rows from dirty reads, or perhaps duplicates due to the data moving in the table while you read it? Or perhaps even different versions of the same row, as it both moved and changed while you read the data.

Comment: trying to add two csv files to show the results.  What is the best way to add documents?

Comment: @Larnu yes i know what NO LOCK does.  I missed it on MPLINE, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm not saying **ADD IT** @PaulKalathas , I'm saying remove them. *Remove them **all***... Like I said, if you *really* need them, change the isolation level, don't spam the hint; it's an awful habit.

Comment: @Larnu - thanks for the tip.  Will do.  Any suggestion on how best to add results as i have them now in CSV file.  How best to add to this question for people to reference.

Comment: @jarlh - please find update question with result data.

Comment: @Larnu I think it much more likely that this data simply exists in the database,  and these rows are showing up because the data is there, rather than some obscure scenario around dirty reads occurring every time the query is run.

Comment: That's the only column you're adding from the MX.TFNO table, so I suggest your join condition is such that you have multiple rows being returned from that table for each row in the rest of the query;  you need to debug it to work out why that is, it depends entirely on your database structure and data.

Comment: I would start by changing your query to JUST look at the MP and MX tables remove 'DISTINCT' and see exactly what data you get back.

Comment: @JeffUK Thanks for your comments.  I have queried the database only on table MPHEAD for TFNO field for a selected PO which has returned blank because there is no data in TFNO field for that selected PO however, per my example data provided, when i add MX.TFNO, there are duplicate records created with data that does not exist against the PO being reviewed.  I will review your other suggestions and see what the results are. Thanks.

Comment: If you were to remove the `distinct` part of your query (without joining to the table), you'd probably find that you still get the "duplicate" lines. This is a frequent misunderstanding. If you need that column of data, the only way to show is to show it on different lines because it has different values.

Answer (score 1):

The issue found was actually an issue in the database which we needed the software developer to provide a fix.  When the fix was installed and I ran the query the issues was resolved and the report for this was pushed into production environment and now being used.